# Web Assembly (Wasm), garbage collection

Tags: performance, assembly, garbage-collection, webassembly

I heard Webassembly will be a compilation target for statically typed languages and can be run in the browser. Claims were made that it could run in the browser at (close to) native speed. This is because the Wasm is relatively close to the machine instructions of the appropriate machine.

However there are 2 types of languages that can compile to Wasm:

1. Languages with garbage collection, e.g. Java, C#
2. Languages without garbage collection, e.g. C/C++, Rust

My current understanding is that garbage collection is a process which negatively affects performance because it requires CPU cycles.

### Question:

Could there be a difference in performance if a Wasm program is either written in a language which has garbage collection versus a language that has none?

Comment: One would have to assume if there's a performance difference in languages that can compile to actual machine code like Java, C#, C/C++ and Rust, that there would be a performance difference in languages when WASM is used as an intermediate when compiling to actual machine code.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if there was some magic way for Wasm to make those garbage collection CPU cycles go away, languages like Java and C# would already be using it.

Comment: Keep in mind there is nothing in C++ preventing you to use garbage collection library... The difference between Java and C++ is, that JVM enforces GC on you, while in C++ you can implement it as you wish (i.e. write your own mechanism or use some library). From the machine code point of view there's then no difference, the GC code runs either as part of the JVM or as part of the app itself, CPU doesn't bother with such subtleties, it does execute only instructions themselves. So your question boils down to "does running more instructions cost more cycles?" = "yes".

Comment: that said I have no idea how wasm deals with JVM environment for Java binaries, probably adds some implementation/emulation layer providing such complex environment, so starting with less demanding language like C may eventually produce learner wasm version, if you don't need those features much and can live with the simpler environment. Also the GC can be often run at particular spots of app where the extra cycles don't affect user experience as much, so while I'm personally strongly biased to C++ and controlling memory, the GC variants can be usable too. And wasm is only "close" to native.

Comment: @Ped7g, that is not correct. The only form of GC that you can generally implement without support from the compiler and runtime system is conservative GC, which usually has significantly worse performance characteristics than precise GC (in both space and time), and furthermore is not able to do things like multiple generations, incrementality, or compaction.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg ? you are the runtime in C++, so you can write your own support for direct GC as well (and own JIT compiler and recompile part of your sources at fly with that GC support). I mean, the C# runtime, firefox, chromium, many JVMs, ... are written in C or C++ itself. It just doesn't make sense to bother with GC if you are writing C++ directly, as the memory management is very easy (if you design your memory usage and source structure accordingly ... takes only about of decade+ of experience to foresee how to write it well...) and performance is then superior to any GC.

Comment: @Ped7g, in a runtime with built-in GC, that GC does not operate on its own object implementation but on the subject of the implementation. The subject is typically a language with much stronger invariants than C++. And even if both are in the same language, the two instances operate in completely different universes (unless your implementation is meta-circular). I won't comment on the claim that memory management is "very easy", other than saying that it is false for any use case where life times are not strictly nested. Once you need lots of reference counting, GC typically is more efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GC proposal is intended to be strictly pay-as-you-go. That is, a program not making use of related instructions should not be affected in any way.

Another way to think about it, at least as far as current browser implementations of Wasm are concerned, is that the GC proposal simply gives you a way to access the same heap that JavaScript values live in. That heap exists whether or not Wasm uses it, and when it doesn't, there is no difference to the current situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you mean with pay-as-you-go that e.g. a C++ program doesn't use GC and thus doesn't have to pay the price of the instruction accompanied with it? (Whereas e.g Java compiled WASM program does have instructions for GC and does have to pay for it with CPU cycles)

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen, yes. In a first approximation, the only thing that actually costs you about GC is performing it. And if you don't allocate anything you won't ever run it.